# unable extract the files from spring tool suite

Tags: spring-tool-suite

while I am extracting files from spring tools suite it throughing exception as path is too long it extracting only upto 80% after it terminating the process .when i try to run the application it is coudn't open the file.I tried many ways to resolve this but still it showing same error.The error was it showing path is too long to solve that problem i tried to store that in minimum path length.But it it is not working

Comment: The standard download of the distribution comes as a self-extracting JAR file. Do you see the issue when running this self-extracting JAR? Or do you download a ZIP and extract that yourself? In that case, you need to use something like 7zip to extract it to circumvent the long-path issues.